# Zend 2 Dynamic dependent Drop-down with DB call

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, zend-framework2

For a quick summary of the below question, I am trying to do http://demos.9lessons.info/sections_demo.php in Zend Framework 2 with a call back to the database.

For example, let's say that Country list had 50 values (Meaning 50 rows in my "country" table), and each Country could have 1,000 Cities (50 x 1,000 = 50,000 Cities in my "cities" table).

Using Zend, I can pull the Country list without a problem, but how do I run my SQL to only select the 1,000 Cities I care about in the second drop-down.

Do I do this outside of the controller and form and do it right on the edit.phtml page?

Answer (score 0):

in example you posted, Cities are not loaded with countries on server side. From server comes set of countries and empty list of cities. When you select country, some JavaScript code of the example ask asynchronously server for set country's cities (it send request to ajax_city.php).
So in this case, you need two actions in your controller. One is for form creation and display it to user and second for cities request.

Comment: Yes, With that example I was more showing the effect of what I'm going for, not how they are doing it.  As for what you mentioned with 2 actions in my controller, how can the action be called on the controller and dynamically update?  Would you be able to provide an example?

Comment: I tried to create some example and hope there is no typo. Here is server side ZF2 controller [http://pastie.org/10235899] and there is javascript side [http://pastie.org/10235912].

Comment: I haven't had time to complete this yet, but it definitely got me in the right direction.  Thank you for helping with the sample code.  I'll update and mark this as right once I get everything working.